# Looping through array of objects PHP

Tags: php

How can I loop through a PHP array of objects (the objects are books with title and price) and output the one whose title comes after the letter R alphabetically?
Thanks

Should I create an array with alphabetic letters then merge that array with book's array (in this case `bookInformation`)?

```
class Book {

    public $title;
    public $price;

    public function __construct($title, $price) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->price = $price;
    }
       public function info() {
        echo $this->title . ' is ' . $this->price . '<br>';  

    } 
}

$bookOne = new Book("Mall", 13.95);
$bookTwo = new Book("Will", 23.99);

$bookOne->info();
$bookTwo->info();

$bookInformation = [$bookOne, $bookTwo];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to find all the books whose title comes after `R`, then sort that list by title using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and then printing the first element in the sorted list:

```
$fBooks = array_filter($bookInformation, function ($v) { return substr($v->title, 0, 1) > 'R'; });
if (count($fBooks)) {
    usort($fBooks, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a->title, $b->title); });
    print_r($fBooks[0]);
}
else {
    echo "no book found!";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BGsRl)

Answer (score 0):

Use array_column
Function

```
$Arraya = [ 'ObjA' => { 'title' => "booka", 'page' => 27, }, 'Objb' => { 'title' => "bookb", 'page' => 37, }, ];
$ArrayofArray = json_decode(json_encode($Arraya), 1);
$titles = array_column($ArrayofArray, "title");
```

Here `$title` return array of title

Comment: You can use `array_column` directly on an array of objects. https://3v4l.org/3ZXGA